# Reportlab - acroForm - numbers (ocr capable)

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, reportlab

i' m using the acroForm library from Reportlab, and i' d like to create a fillable entity for numbers - if possible ocr capable (like here: http://87.229.108.143/files/ocr_4TiHklptb.png) .

What would be important is when i fill a 'rectangle', the focus should jump to the next 'rectangle'.

Could anybody give me suggestions where to start it?

Thanks.

Comment: Search for field attribute COMB

Comment: The only one place where i found this comb attribute is in reportlab.acroform / fieldFlagValues, but i don' t see it is used anywhere. How would it help to me? Please tell me more.